# Lost access to external Google login

Tags: google-docs, google-workspace-for-business, account-recovery

I was using my university address with Google web services. Now after my graduation I cannot access this university account any more. However, there are still important documents on my Google Docs.

When I try to log into Google Docs, it will recognise the domain of my email address and forward me to an external login page which is hosted by my university.

Is there any way to log directly into my Google account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The administrator of G Suite for your university should tell you if they enabled that option.